# how to remove all requests of js and css from wordpress ( Themes and Plugins )

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I want to remove all css and js that are loaded by default and I will replace those js and css manually.
(Frontend js and css only).

I want to improve performance. I also want to do this for better management

I have a different server that's optimized for static files.  I host all static files on a sub-domain like static.example.com

Answer (score 2):

You can wp_print_styles and wp_print_scripts action hooks and then get the global $wp_styles and $wp_scripts object variables in their respective hooks.

The "registered" attribute lists registered scripts and the "queue" attribute lists queue scripts on both of the above objects.

An example code to empty the scripts and style queue.

```
function pm_remove_all_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    $wp_scripts->queue = array();
}
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'pm_remove_all_scripts', 100);
function pm_remove_all_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;
    $wp_styles->queue = array();
}
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'pm_remove_all_styles', 100);
```

Credit:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/17138

Comment: this will remove only frontend css and js only or all scripts including wordpress dashboard ones

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress, in order for setup to happen properly on page load, all assets need to be enqueued in the functions.php file. It is not going to make your site load any faster to take them out of the enqueue - and you are likely to break the site if you attempt to hard code the paths to the assets.

Comment: well my plan is simple get all files host on my other server only problem is that I want to remove all css and js frontend only

Comment: As I said, all script and CSS imports in wordpress are done though the enqueue hook. These ARE your front end files. To change them, you need to edit the enqueues in functions.php - but if you take them completely out of the enqueue your site will not load properly.

Comment: now what I am doing is remove js and css that using enqueues and add that files using simple html scripts and stylesheet tags so by  doing this I can use custom subdomain and url